# Understanding types in higher order functions in Scala

Tags: scala, types, higher-order-functions

I'm teaching myself Scala (coming from many years of Java) and I came across the following code, which I cannot fully grok:

```
case class Email(subject: String, text: String, sender: String, recipient: String)

type EmailFilter = Email => Boolean
def newMailsForUser(mails: Seq[Email], f: EmailFilter) = mails.filter(f)

val sentByOneOf: Set[String] => EmailFilter =
  senders => email => senders.contains(email.sender)

val notSentByAnyOf: Set[String] => EmailFilter =
  senders => email => !senders.contains(email.sender)

val minimumSize: Int => EmailFilter = n => email => email.text.size >= n
val maximumSize: Int => EmailFilter = n => email => email.text.size <= n
```

The parts I find hard to understand are the vals with missing type definitions:

```
val sentByOneOf: Set[String] => EmailFilter =
  senders => email => senders.contains(email.sender)
```

I created the same functions using `def` which I can understand:

```
def sentByOne(senders: Set[String], email: Email): (Set[String] => EmailFilter) = {
  senders => email => senders.contains(email.sender)
}
```

Where does the type come from in the former version? Also, is the latter version preferable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, in this definiton :

```
val sentByOneOf: Set[String] => EmailFilter =  
  senders => email => senders.contains(email.sender)
```

expands to:

```
val sentByOneOf: Set[String] => Email => Boolean = 
  senders => email => senders.contains(email.sender)
```

type is defined after `:` as `Set[String] => EmailFilter`. So First value that is passed to `sentByOneOf` is `Set[String]` and second is of type `EmailFilter` which is an alias for `Email => Boolean`.

Longer version:

As all variables/values in Scala, type can be specified after colon like it is in this example or it can be infered from the expression it refers to. So in here:

```
val sentByOneOf = (senders: Set[String]) => (email: Email) => 
  senders.contains(email.sender)
```

type of `sentByOneOf` would also be infered to `sentByOneOf: Set[String] => (Email => Boolean)` where `Email => Boolean` has an alias defined as `EmailFilter`

In scala `function values`, which is what you have here actually, are in reality instances of `FunctioN` class where N is number of variables. So your function `sentByOneOf` is actually this:

```
val sentByOneOf = new Function2[Set[String], Email, Boolean] { 
  def apply(senders: Set[String], email: Email, pred: => Boolean): Boolean = senders.contains(email.sender)
}
```

BTW you chose great series of articles but rather difficult as for first time with Scala :)

Comment: Where are the types for `senders` and `email`?